# border-radius renders edges from gradient-background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm trying to get a nav with bootstrap (nav-pills with justify) and only want the border-radius at the left edges from the first item and at the right edges from the last item. (this works with no problem at all)

but on the first item chrome (i didn't tested other browsers yet) renders the color of the gradient-background from non-active/non-hover in the edges on the radius.

on the last item it works (hover mouse and you'll see)

bootply: http://www.bootply.com/MeZAUi07EK

Any suggestion how to fix that?

Comment: I don't see the issue you are describing in Chrome.  Can you provide a mockup of the expected behavior, and a screenshot of the actual behavior?

Comment: Same here, in chrome, I do not see any issues at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out - instead `background-image` try `background`

**CSS**

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #f3f8fc 100%, #f3f8fc 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: #f3f8fc;
    color: #7ba4d0;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/54/)**